# Hive: Querying the table to match the conditions

Tags: hive, hiveql

Have a table in Hive with the following data. Which I am trying to play around with:

```
A   B   C   D 
==============
76  5   0.6 107777
78  5   0.5 107777
79  5   0.5 107777
79  5   0.5 107777
80  5   0.5 107777
210 5   0.5 107777
211 5   0.5 107777
213 5   0.5 107777
316 5   0.5 107777
316 5   0.5 107777
76  7   0.5 102997
78  7   0.5 102997
79  8   0.5 102997
79  8   0.5 102997
80  9   0.5 108997
80  9   0.5 108997
80  9   0.5 108997


Need to count the 'B and D' when B>4 and C is not same for B and D.
```

Expected O/P:

Here looking for the values where, Value in 'C' is not present for the same value in 'A' and 'B'. Along with displaying the duplicate values (more than 1) present in the table.

```
Value in 'C' is not present for the same value in 'A' and 'B':
```

This means that

```
A B C
=====
76 5 0.6 => OK
78 5 0.5 => OK
79 5 0.5 => OK 
79 5 0.5 => NOT OK (As C=0.5 shouldn't have repetitive value for same A and B value)
80 5 0.5 => OK.....




A   B   C   D 
==============
79  5   0.5 107777
316 5   0.5 107777
79  8   0.5 102997
80  9   0.5 108997
80  9   0.5 108997

Count: 5
```

Been able to write the query for the first part but not getting any breakthrough for the remaining part:

```
SELECT A,B,C,D FROM DB.TABLE1 WHERE B >1;
```

but not getting how to write for the last part:

```
count the 'B and D' when B>4 and C is not same for B and D.
```

Any suggestion on this will be really helpful.

Update_1:

Tried the below:

```
 SELECT A,B,C,D FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE B >4) t1 GROUP BY B,D HAVING countnum>1 LIMIT 20;
```

but getting error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 1:197 Expression not in GROUP BY key '1'
hive>
```

Comment: I don't see why you are getting five rows in the result set.  And why isn't the first row in the result set?

Comment: what does 'C is not same for B and D' mean?

Comment: @GordonLinoff,@Steve Thanks. I have updated my question with further details.

Comment: so you want to remove both the rows or just one.

Comment: @GaurangShah Keeping one and removing all the others i.e. counting the total number of such rows.

Comment: if you want to count total number of rows just apply `groupby` on A and B and filter result with count > 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Need to count the 'B and D' when B>4 and C is not same for B and D.`

Input: `table1`

```
A   B   C   D 
==============
76  5   0.6 107777
78  5   0.5 107777
79  5   0.5 107777
79  5   0.5 107777
80  5   0.5 107777
210 5   0.5 107777
211 5   0.5 107777
213 5   0.5 107777
316 5   0.5 107777
316 5   0.5 107777
76  7   0.5 102997
78  7   0.5 102997
79  8   0.5 102997
79  8   0.5 102997
80  9   0.5 108997
80  9   0.5 108997
80  9   0.5 108997
```

Query:

```
select count(*)
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by B, C, D) as rn
  from table1
  where B>4
) as t1
where rn=1;
```

Output: `5`

Explanation: `row_number()` gives row numbers based on values of `B`, `C` and `D`. For rows with same values for these three variables, row number will be keep on incremented.

```
A   B   C   D       rn
======================
76  5   0.6 107777  1
78  5   0.5 107777  1
79  5   0.5 107777  2
79  5   0.5 107777  3
80  5   0.5 107777  4
210 5   0.5 107777  5
211 5   0.5 107777  6
213 5   0.5 107777  7
316 5   0.5 107777  8
316 5   0.5 107777  9
76  7   0.5 102997  1
78  7   0.5 102997  2
79  8   0.5 102997  1
79  8   0.5 102997  2
80  9   0.5 108997  1
80  9   0.5 108997  2
80  9   0.5 108997  3
```